# Optional trailing slash in url in url-config of web-site

Tags: web-services, http, rest, url, web

If I define url like `"^optional/slash/?&"` - and so web-page to which it bound will available   by both url versions - with slash and without - will I violate any conventions or standards by doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Are you saying you wish to have `http://example.com/somepage/` be equivalent to `http://example.com/somepage`?

Comment: @BigMacAttack Exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't a **redirection** be more appropriate?

If I remember correctly, trailing slashes should be used with resources that *list* other resources. Like a directory that lists files, a list of articles or a category query (e.g http://www.example.com/category/cakes/). Without trailing slashes the URI should point to a single resource. Like a file, an article or a complex query with parameters (e.g http://www.example.com/search?ingredients=strawberry&taste=good)

Just use the *HTTP code 302 FOUND* to redirect typos to their correct URIs.

**EDIT**: Thanks to AndreD for pointing it out, a *HTTP code 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY* is more appropriate for **permanently** aliasing typos. Search engines and other clients should stop querying for the misspelled URL after getting a 301 code once, and [Google recommends using it for changing the URL of a page in their index](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).

Comment: Why do you recommend 302 instead of 301?

Comment: @AndreD Yes, I see now. In this [*outdated* HTTP document](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html#z9) I had read it made it seem that the 302 code is more suitable for aliasing URLs. However is this more [up-to-date HTTP document](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) their use becomes better defined. I was misled by the codes' nicknames.

Answer (score 3):

According to [RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):
Section 6.2.4. Protocol-Based Normalization -
*"Substantial effort to reduce the incidence of false negatives is
   often cost-effective for web spiders.  Therefore, they implement even
   more aggressive techniques in URI comparison.  For example, if they
   observe that a URI such as

      `http://example.com/data`

   redirects to a URI differing only in the trailing slash

      `http://example.com/data/`

   they will likely regard the two as equivalent in the future.  This
   kind of technique is only appropriate when equivalence is clearly
   indicated by both the result of accessing the resources and the
   common conventions of their scheme's dereference algorithm (in this
   case, use of redirection by HTTP origin servers to avoid problems
   with relative references)."*

My interpretation of this statement would be that making the two URIs functionally equivalent (e.g. by means of an .htaccess statement, redirect, or similar) does not violate any standard conventions. According to the RFC, web spiders are prepared to treat them functionally equivalent if they point to the same resource.

Comment: I'd always heard that a single canonical URL was important for SEO: http://moz.com/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps I always wondered why spiders couldn't just munge the two; I guess they do...

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not violating any standards by doing that you can Use this Optional trailing slash in URL of websites 
but you need to stay on the safe side, because there are different ways servers handle the issue:

- Sometimes, it doesn't matter for SEO: many web servers will just re-direct using 301 status code to the default version;
- Some web servers may return a 404 page for the non-trailing-slash address = wasted link juice and efforts;
- Some web servers may return 302 redirect to the correct version = wasted link juice and efforts;
- Some web servers may return 200 response for both the versions = wasted link juice and efforts as well as potential duplicate content problems.